# javascript to access a specific css selector property

Tags: javascript, css

I have this in a  css file

```
.datagrid table tbody td { color: #00496B; border-left: 1px solid
    #E1EEF4; font-size: 16px ;font-weight: normal; }
```

how can I use javascript to change the font-size dynamically?
this following codes worked on all td but how can I access the specific td under .datagrid?
any help is appreciated.

```
css('td', 'font-size', '9px');
function css(selector, property, value) {
      for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length;i++) {//Loop through all styles
          //Try add rule
          try { document.styleSheets[i].insertRule(selector+ ' {'+property+':'+value+'}', document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length);
          } catch(err) {try { document.styleSheets[i].addRule(selector, property+':'+value);} catch(err) {}}//IE
      }
}
```

Comment: You didn't try it with the selector `.datagrid table tbody td` instead?

Comment: The easiest way to change the font size for all the tables dynamically would be having the data grids inherit the font size from a container, and changing the `class` of the container to one that specifies a larger font. Analogously, for changing a single cell, just add a class (say `highlight`) that would give it a larger font `td.highlight { font-size: 20px; }`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of traversing the CSS, you might use `document.getElementById` to select the element if it has a unique ID, otherwise you can use `getElementByTagName` as follows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0] //the first div in the document
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1] //the second div... etc...
```

then you can change the inline css e.g. `<div id="mydiv" style="width: 200px;">`

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.width = "200px"
```

If, otherwise, you don't want to insert inline styles, you can access the external CSS with `document.styleSheets[index]`, where index is used if you have more than one stylesheeet, otherwise just use `document.styleSheets[0]`, then the rules are in another array, which is `cssRules[index]` so e.g. with `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]` you select the first rule of the first external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to map css rules is to use querySelectorAll:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".datagrid table tbody td")
```

This is supported in all recent browsers.

If you are targeting a single element:

```
document.querySelector(".datagrid table tbody td")
```

And to modify the font size on this specific element:

```
document.querySelector(".datagrid table tbody td").style.fontSize="12px";
```